# BackupPc doesn't backup mounted LVM Snapshot?

Tags: backup, rsync, lvm

I resetup my BackupPc and running into a problem:

I want to backup "/backup" on all hosts. I started with ONE host for test purposes.

Process:

1. BackupPC calls a Shell-Script on the Client
2. That script generates some snapshots and Mount them to /backup/...
3. Now BackupPC should backup
4. At least BackupPC calls another Shell-Script, which unmounts and removes the snapshots

The /backup gets "backed up" but just the Folder, not their Contents.

I enhanced the first shell-script to make sure the Folders have Content, here the Output:

```
2017-06-04 20:11:14 Created directory /data/backuppc/pc/v3.lipperts-web.de/refCnt
2017-06-04 20:11:15 Output from DumpPreUserCmd:   Reducing COW size 5,00 GiB down to maximum usable size 256,00 MiB.
2017-06-04 20:11:15 Output from DumpPreUserCmd:   Logical volume "snaptshot-zabbix" created
2017-06-04 20:11:15 Output from DumpPreUserCmd:   Reducing COW size 5,00 GiB down to maximum usable size 256,00 MiB.
2017-06-04 20:11:15 Output from DumpPreUserCmd:   Logical volume "snaptshot-filebeat" created
2017-06-04 20:11:15 Output from DumpPreUserCmd:   Reducing COW size 5,00 GiB down to maximum usable size 1,01 GiB.
2017-06-04 20:11:15 Output from DumpPreUserCmd:   Logical volume "snaptshot-teamspeak" created
2017-06-04 20:11:16 Output from DumpPreUserCmd:   Logical volume "snaptshot-schnoddi" created
2017-06-04 20:11:16 Output from DumpPreUserCmd:   Logical volume "snaptshot-sentry" created
2017-06-04 20:11:16 Output from DumpPreUserCmd:   Reducing COW size 5,00 GiB down to maximum usable size 256,00 MiB.
2017-06-04 20:11:16 Output from DumpPreUserCmd:   Logical volume "snaptshot-nginx" created
2017-06-04 20:11:16 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: insgesamt 13
2017-06-04 20:11:16 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   329 Jun  3 17:43 docker-compose.yml
2017-06-04 20:11:16 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: drwx------ 2 root root 12288 Jun  3 17:43 lost+found
2017-06-04 20:11:16 full backup started for directory /backup
2017-06-04 20:11:17 Output from DumpPostUserCmd:   Logical volume "snaptshot-zabbix" successfully removed
2017-06-04 20:11:17 Output from DumpPostUserCmd:   Logical volume "snaptshot-filebeat" successfully removed
2017-06-04 20:11:17 Output from DumpPostUserCmd:   Logical volume "snaptshot-teamspeak" successfully removed
2017-06-04 20:11:17 Output from DumpPostUserCmd:   Logical volume "snaptshot-schnoddi" successfully removed
2017-06-04 20:11:17 Output from DumpPostUserCmd:   Logical volume "snaptshot-sentry" successfully removed
2017-06-04 20:11:18 Output from DumpPostUserCmd:   Logical volume "snaptshot-nginx" successfully removed
2017-06-04 20:11:18 Got fatal error during xfer (No files dumped for share /backup)
2017-06-04 20:11:23 Backup aborted (No files dumped for share /backup)
```

You can se there is an File listed "docker-compose.yml", but backup is empty

https://i.stack.imgur.com/58xJT.png

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing RsyncArgs from Default to the Args which I had (by Default) in BackupPC 3 it worked:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsND8.jpg